# SQL transactions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, transactions

How do you perform a transaction of SQL in JavaScript. I have already connected the db in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already made a connection to your database, all you have to do is execute your query as follows:

```
var x = 8;    
DATABASE_NAME.db.transaction(function(transaction){
            transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE testID = ?", [x], 
            function (transaction, result){
                 //write your success function call here
            }, //onDone function
            function (transaction, error){
                //write your fail function call here
             }  //onFail function
        );
    })
```

As you can see, the passed variable `x` is used to include its value instead of the `?`

Comment: why are the [] ?

Comment: @DabdulLayfield inside the [] you right any values you want to pass from your javascript to the query. I will edit the post with an example.

Comment: good I understand thank you sir